# Finding max value for a column containing hierarchical decimals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where the column values are like '1.2.4.5', '3.11.0.6',
'3.9.3.14','1.4.5.6.7', N/A, etc.. I want to find the max of that particular column. However when i use this query i am not getting the max value.

```
(SELECT  max (CASE WHEN mycolumn = 'N/A'
        THEN '-1000'
        ELSE mycolumn
        END )
FROM mytable
WHERE column like 'abc')
```

I am getting 3.9.3.14 as max value instead of 3.11....

Can someone help me?

Comment: This is for MS SQL

Comment: Do you mean .. '1.2.4.5' max is 5 , '3.11.0.6' max is 11 , '3.9.3.14' max is 14,therefore Max is 14 ?

Comment: Nope max value of all those values  ie '1.2.4.5' is one value so max of ('1.2.4.5', '3.11.0.6', '3.9.3.14','1.4.5.6.7', N/A ...) these values

Comment: Don't change 'N/A' to '-1000', but to '0.0.0.0' in order to stay consistent with the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAX()` on values stored as text performs an alphabetic sort.
Use [`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql) and [`HIERARCHYID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference):

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRST_VALUE(t.mycolumn) OVER(
                ORDER BY CONVERT(HIERARCHYID, '/' + REPLACE(NULLIF(t.mycolumn,'N/A'), '.', '/') + '/') DESC) AS [Max]
FROM #mytable t
```

Answer (score 6):

Those aren't really decimals - they're strings containing *multiple* dots, so it's unhelpful to think of them as being "decimals".

We can accomplish your query with a bit of manipulation. There is a type build into SQL Server that more naturally represents this type of structure - [`hierarchyid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference). If we convert your values to this type then we can find the `MAX` fairly easily:

```
 declare @t table (val varchar(93) not null)
 insert into @t(val) values
 ('1.2.4.5'),
 ('3.11.0.6'),
 ('3.9.3.14'),
 ('1.4.5.6.7')

 select MAX(CONVERT(hierarchyid,'/' + REPLACE(val,'.','/') + '/')).ToString()
 from @t
```

Result:

```
/3/11/0/6/
```

I leave the exercise of fully converting this string representation back into the original form as an exercise for the reader. Alternatively, I'd suggest that you may want to start *storing* your data using this datatype anyway.

Comment: will max(replace(columnname,'.','')) fetch the max value as '31106' ?

Comment: @Coder1991 - it would in this trivial example but once you introduce more multi-digit components you'll get ambiguity and wrong results. E.g. if we add `31.0.0.6` to the sample, it wouldn't be the max by your technique since `3.11.0.6` would still sort higher.

Comment: if we are going to consider it as a number then 31106 is the max one since 31006 is lesser than 31106. Sorry if I'm confusing you.

Comment: @Coder1991 - the point is that these are *not* numbers. They're strings composed of digits, true, but there the resemblance stops. Think of them like e.g. section numbers in a document. `3.11.0.6` is the 6th subsection of the 0th subsection of the 11th section of the 3rd chapter.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation.